# How do you create a proper 'include' directory?

Tags: c++, header, software-distribution

So, we have all seen (some of you guys might have even made) professional libraries which have proper include directories which contain all the header files you need to use the library. An example would be the OpenCV library include folder which I have attached.

[image]

When we release libraries, what we do is just zip the headers for the lib and ask the recipient to extract them to somewhere convenient, which is, to be honest, quite fine. However, I would like to make an 'include' directory with all relevant headers if possible because I feel that my distribution can be organized better that way. How can we go about doing that?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please add more details on what you want from this include distribution

Comment: @VadimKotov Something like what happens when I build OpenCV, it makes a neat install directory inside my build dir, where it keeps the necessary header files in the 'include' dir and the libs in the x64 dir.

Comment: I think OpenCV uses Cmake to automate build and installation. You should take a look at Cmake https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/install.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a folder for all neccessary headers and specify path considering that folder when include them in code.
You can also specify that folder in preferences of your project, for example Visual Studio or Eclipse allow it, so you shouldn't write full path for those includes.

Comment: I mean, some libraries like OpenCV create a nice directory called install which is meant to be distributed to other projects. (See the attached image)

Comment: so why not two attach all files you need and zip them? Or you are interested how to create an installer that will create all dirs with files inside?

Comment: I do the zipping thing now. It just seems non-elegant.

Comment: So then another way is creating a full installer. But actually most part of libs I have seen are just zipped and it's normal.